# How to make the footer at the bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

There's are some pages in my website which content is little,

```
the content height + footer height < one screen height
```

See the picture below:

[image]

So my question is how can I make the footer at the bottom of the page when my content's height is not enough to cover the full page?

PS: I don't want the footer page fixed at the bottom.

Comment: Show us your CSS an footer element

Comment: if you don't want your footer to be fixed then apply min-height to your content

Comment: @C-Link could you explain it more detailed?

Comment: @Charlie That's not what I want, because it's the footer is fixed at the bottom

Comment: If you don't want to apply a min-height to your content, you could also change the background color to achieve the allusion that your footer extends all the way to the bottom of the page. But in order for us to help you more, we need to see code.

Comment: I agree with @BigMacAttack.  Forget the hacks, just color your page background a dark color to match the footer.  It'll look better and work better than any of this other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yvZaV/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>content here, this will push the footer down the page if it is needed</div>
    <footer>footer here</footer>
</div>

html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: The author did mention that he doesn't want to fix the footer to the bottom of the page.

Comment: it gets pushed down when the content pushes it down

Comment: I think absolute positioning may cause other problems...

Comment: got an example of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [min-height](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/min-height) to your content, you can set it in pixels or in %

```
.content{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvZaV/2/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/